# convert UTC time to EPOCH seconds in Javascript

Tags: javascript

2020-08-01 11:53:25.85088067 +0000 UTC m=+154637.818754072

I am receiving time in this format , need help to convert it to
1st August 2020 11:53AM  in JavaScript

Comment: have you tried with  var tmp= new Date("2020-08-01 11:53:25.85088067")?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use moment library. Try this:

```js
let moment = require('moment');

let dateString = "2020-08-01 11:53:25.85088067 +0000 UTC m=+154637.818754072"
dateString = dateString.split("+")[0];
let date = new Date(dateString);
let formattedDate = moment(date).format('Do MMMM YYYY, h:mm:ss a');
console.log(formattedDate); //1st August  2020, 11:53:25 am
```

Answer (score 1):

```js
const dateTimeString = "2020-08-01 11:53:25.85088067 +0000 UTC m=+154637.818754072"
const dateTimeArray = dateTimeString.split(' ')
const [date, time] = dateTimeArray
const dateArray = date.split('-')
const timeArray = time.split(':')
const [year, month, day] = dateArray
const [hour, minute, second] = timeArray
const utcDate = new Date(Date.UTC(year, month - 1, day, hour, minute, second));

console.log(utcDate.toUTCString())
console.log(utcDate.getTime() / 1000)
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want the value in second then :

Math.floor(new Date('2011-03-29 17:06:21 UTC') / 1000);
It will give you Unix time in second ..(  In the above example : 1301418381)

If you want full date object :
As per mdn ( https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/UTC)  use this :

var dateString = "2020-08-01 11:53:25.85088067 +0000 UTC m=+154637.818754072"

dateString.toUTCString()

If I understood the question wrong, please comment or reply , so that I can understand it properly. Thanks